# App shows white screen if you click home button and comes back to the app

Tags: android

I have developed an app ,if i opened the app and clicks on home buttom(without closing the app) and opens other apps and again opens my app it shows a white screen without no function .

[image]

Comment: add more details. Like manifest and themes.

Comment: add more details

Answer (score 0):

i think when you press home button then you destroy your application and then when you again open application then its recall